Program in Assembly language for Z80 processor, which reads one-byte numbers x and y and write s the calculated two-byte value
I need to write and execute a program in Assembly language for the processor architectures Intel-8080/Z80, which reads one-byte numbers x and y from two adjacent memory cells and writes the calculated two-byte value of the following expression into the third cell:
f(x, y) + 7f(x, y + 2) + 3f(3x, y)
The function f(x, y) should be implemented in the program ONCE but called THREE times.
f(x, y) = 7x + 2 - 3y
All of that should be done using Z80 Simulator
I tried this code:
ORG 0000h

x:      DB 5
y:      DB 1
result: DW 0

START:
    LD A, (x)
    LD HL, y
    LD B, (HL)

    CALL FUNCTION
    LD HL, RESULT

    LD A, (x)
    ADD A, 2
    LD HL, y
    LD C, (HL)
    LD A, C
    ADD A, 2
    LD C, A
    CALL FUNCTION
    LD BC, RESULT

    ADD HL, BC
    LD A, (x)
    LD HL, y
    LD B, (HL)
    CALL FUNCTION

    LD BC, 1
    LD HL, RESULT
LOOP:
    ADD HL, HL
    INC BC
    LD A, B
    OR C
    CP 12
    JR NC, END_LOOP   
    JR LOOP           
END_LOOP:
    LD (result), HL
    HALT

FUNCTION:
    LD HL, 0
    ADD HL, BC
    ADD HL, HL
    LD A, H
    ADD A, A
    SUB L
    LD (RESULT), HL
    RET

but I don't see in what columns I would see my needed result and I don't know if it really getting it, because I don't see anything to change when I edit x and y values

I don't see FUNCTION computing 7x or +2 — can you share how that's done?  Also, the signature of FUNCTION would be good to have, and the registers associated with the signature items.

@ErikEidt
about function signature and the registers, can you please explain it a little bit further?
FUNCTION:
; Function f(x,y) = 7x + 2x - 3y
LD HL, 0        ; Clear HL register pair
ADD HL, BC      ; Add x to HL (7x)
ADD HL, HL      ; Multiply x by 2 (2x)
LD A, H         ; Load H into A (high byte of HL)
ADD A, A        ; Multiply H by 2
SUB L           ; Subtract L (low byte of HL) from A (now A contains 7x + 2x - 3y)
LD (RESULT), HL ; Store the result in the RESULT variable
RET             ; Return from the function

A function signature is something that describes the parameters & their types & return value & types.  Like int f (byte x, byte y) -or- int f(int x, int y) — fyi big difference between those two.  Then a mapping from those signature items to registers and/or stack or memory locations for assembly.

So you're saying that's doing 7x with a single ADD instruction using BC?  I guess I don't get that magic.  Also, caller only puts some value in B, but nothing in C?

@ErikEidt how exactly should I add those signatures to my code? I tried to write FUNCTION (int x. int y) but z80 simulator said that syntax in this line is wrong. About my method of doing 7x and +2, can you please tell which way I can do that?

Add them to your code as comments.  Though this is for MIPS code, this documents the function signature and register usages for parameter and return value.  See https://ecs-network.serv.pacific.edu/ecpe-170/tutorials/example5_function_with_stack.asm/view . Look for "# FUNCTION: int fun(int a)" and read that comment section.

See also lines 61-66 here: https://github.com/breakintoprogram/lib-spectrum/blob/master/lib/scroll_attr.z80, and 63-66 here: https://github.com/breakintoprogram/lib-spectrum/blob/master/lib/sprite.z80

This kind of information is needed if you want to share your code with others, e.g. here at StackOverflow.

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the tour to learn how this site works, it is not a forum. Then come back and [edit] your question to clarify. do not add a comment for this.

"I don't see in what columns I would see my needed result" Please elaborate, what do you mean? What columns do you mean?

Your source does not at all what the formulas require. There are so many errors, you might want to step back and try with a smaller step first.
